# How to get all audio devices for Android APIs < 23

Tags: webrtc, android-4.4-kitkat, android-audiomanager, audio-device

how can i get all device info not using the method of api 23 ?

```
AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_ALL); //or GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS
```

is there any way?

In this case the target api is 19 - KitKat.

Thank you.

Comment: do you found solve?